Three teens have sex with mom at teen-comedy 80s movie
Genre: Comedy - teen movie  
Date : 80s
Language: English
Country: USA
Maybe Rated R for Sex & Nudity
Details: There are three young friends who have nice time to do many recklessness and crazy things. They loved sexy adventures. I remember they met an old mom but still sexy and then she takes first one with her in bedroom, having sex, the other two friends saw them through keyhole. After he is finished, she called the second one to have sex too with her, etc.,
When her man back home, they run over stairs.

This movie can be teen movie , as it like private school (1983) and that sex comedy - B movies at 80s.
Additional details : probably it's the same movie that three young friends have sex with whore who had "Pediculus pubis" , so they had infected and found themselves in embarrassing situation at party. 


You're sure this wasn't a porno?

no , did you watch private school (1983)  before ?

The OP didn't say they had sex on screen.  The line between porn and not-porn can be pretty thin sometimes.

Steve-O ,, exactly , may be the lady was topless but it wasn't explicit sex scene
